# How to delete cookies of IE, Chrome and FF browsers with Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, cookies, browser, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver. After successful completion of first test execution browsers are responding slowly and remaining tests are failing. How to delete cookies of IE, Chrome and FF browsers by using Selenium WebDriver with Java? 
Can any one please help me out?

Thanks,
Nagaraju

Answer (score 4):

To delete cookies do:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()
```

Bear in mind that this will only affect locally modifiable cookies (ones you can see in the JavaScript console using `document.cookie`), not HTTPOnly ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.manage().cookies.deleteallcookies()
```